# How to lock remote windows (7 and 10) computers

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, lock

I'm trying to lock all computers in my house - I checked the psshutdown option with the -l flag, but although the shutdown is working, the lock isn't working at all - it's writing that the machine is locked, but it's not actually locked.
I also tried with `psexec \\192.168.14.100 -s -u {username} -p {password} c:\1.bat` - and there I put the `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` (the file is working locally) - but it's writing as if it succeeded, but the windows machine isn't locked.

Any ideas? (by using the previous programs - or any new ones).

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com. As you indicate that the rundll32.exe bat file works locally, you need to find out : why it doesn't work when using it via a remote machine using psexec. Maybe this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151412/psexec-fails-against-windows-10-remote-target ) can show you some things to check? and let us know if the problem remains afterwards

Comment: @OlivierDulac, thanks for answering. Sadly, this is not the problem. As I said, shutdown (without the -L flag) is working remotely. The only problem is with locking.